# Error installing Net::LDAP on Oracle Enterprise Linux

Tags: linux, perl, centos, cpan

I am trying to install the Net::LDAP module on an OEL box using CPAN, but I get the following error:

```
[root ~]# cpan -i Net::LDAP

CPAN: Storable loaded ok

Going to read /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
Could not pipe[  --decompress --stdout /root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz |]: No such file or directory at /usr/lib/perl5/5.8.8/CPAN.pm line 5726.
```

Can someone please guide me on how to troubleshoot this?

Comment: forgot the mention technology - I am trying the above module installation in perl.

Comment: No need, you already tagged it [tag:perl], that's enough.

Answer (score 0):

CPAN needs to be configured before you can use it to install stuff.

There should be a whole bunch of stuff under

```
/root/.cpan
```

Generally cpan gets this stuff automatically, but for some reason it's 
not there on your machine. In particular it needs this file.

```
/root/.cpan/sources/authors/01mailrc.txt.gz
```

If that file is there, then cpan man be missing the gzip binary needed to uncompress that file.